# replace function not working

Tags: apex, string

Hi replaceAll function in apex, is not replacing every occurance in my string.
Can anyone guide me on this, how to replace every occurrence in string?

```
string body='<p>string 1</p><p><img src="sfdc://0684E000000IBcwQAG" alt="Macros ss2"></img></p><p>string 2<img src="sfdc://0694E000000Lqj0QAC" alt="Screen Shot 2018-09-19 at 2.33.01 PM"></img></p><p> </p><p>test sample post</p>';
string a= body.replaceAll(body.substringBetween('src="sfdc://', '"'),'TEST: ');

system.debug('string'+a);


|DEBUG|string<p>string 1</p><p><img src="sfdc://TEST: " alt="Macros ss2"></img></p><p>string 2<img src="sfdc://0694E000000Lqj0QAC" alt="Screen Shot 2018-09-19 at 2.33.01 PM"></img></p><p> </p><p>test sample post</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only finding the first occurrence, because that's the only ID you end up looking for. Instead, you need to use a regular expression, like this:

```
String a= body.replaceAll('src="sfdc://.+?"','src="sfdc://TEST: "');
```

Or, you could match the prefix and suffix:

```
string a= body.replaceAll('(src="sfdc://).+?(")','$1TEST: $2');
```